# rsync --files-from specifies folders but does not copy files, recursive does not fix it

Tags: linux, rsync

I've just recently revisited a script that I maintained a few years back and trying to get it to work on a new server.

It basically runs the following

```
rsync -vaP --copy-unsafe-links --files-from=dirlist.txt --exclude-from=excludelist.txt . /path/to/backup
```

dirlist.txt is a plain text file that contains directories with files I want synced relative to `.`

```
foo/
foo/bar
foo/bar/gop
foo/tra
foo/bla
foo/bla/rgh
foo/bla/rgh/meh
```

and excludelist.txt is a plain text file that contains the path to specific files within the above directories that I want to exclude from the rsync command.

When I run the above I get

```
/path/to/backup/foo
/path/to/backup/foo/bar
/path/to/backup/foo/bar/gop
/path/to/backup/foo/tra
/path/to/backup/foo/bla
/path/to/backup/foo/bla/rgh
/path/to/backup/foo/bla/rgh/meh
```

But none of the files that were in the source directory were copied over?

I've tried using the `-r` command but then I end up getting directories that I don't want  like `foo/don` or `foo/tco` copied when it runs the rsync for `foo/`.

I know this script has run in the past so I'm very confused as to what has changed (other then maybe the rsync version but I can't track down the version I had last ran on).

Update:
I'm using various versions of rsync from 2.5.7 to 2.6.6. In 2.5.7 it doesn't have --files-from nor --Filter

Comment: Version 2.6.8 of rsync appears to do what I wanted without any additional changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago.

My solution was to opt for the filter rule as follows:

rsync --archive -r --filter="merge fromfile"  --dry-run

```
fromfile
- /el[2-4]*
- "*/ppc/*"
+ /el5
- /*
```

This excludes any sub directories named ppc, any top level directories el2, el3, el4, includes el5 and excludes everything else.

Comment: I'm merging the dirlist.txt and excludelist.txt into one list?

Comment: This also seems to be an issue resolved with 2.6.6 of rsync. Unfortunately I only have one machine that runs this version.